# Escaping values for vim.command, vim.eval in Python vim plugins

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

I'm writing a python plugin for vim and it's looking like the only way to call a specific command is with the `vim.command` function. However, just substituting values into the function seems like a bad idea. How would I escape values so that I can pass untrusted data as an argument into a vim function? As a simple example, let's say I want to echo out untrusted input (I know I could just use print, but this is just an example). I would do something like:

```
value = get_data_from_untrusted_source()
vim.command("echo %s" % value)
```

However, if that untrusted data has a `|` in it, the command is ended and a new one is executed which is bad. Even if I use quotes, we end up with sql injection like attacks where an attacker can just put an apostrophe in their response to end the string. Then if we double quote, it could be possible to put a backslash somewhere to end the quote. For example if we just double quotes we would go from `\'` to `\''` which escapes the first quote.

Basically what I'm asking is if there's a safe way to call vim functions from a python plugin and would appreciate any help.